# Print Dates range if they are available in db

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, xlwt

from below code i am going to print date ranges that's fine but what the problem is i need to print the date ranges , those available in database only [[this image shows the created_at date field which is in look model . I need these dated to be printed if user select the date rage between dec 1 to  dec 30 ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGQve.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGQve.png)

```
while (current_date >= from_date):
     r = r + 1
     ws.write(0,r,current_date,style)
     current_date -= timedelta(days = 1)
```

models.py

```
class Look(models.Model):
     created_at = models.DateField()
```